# Delay of WMS-Request after MouseWheelZoom

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I want that there will be a delay of some milliseconds between MouseWheelZoom and a execution of the WMS-Request (I use single tile wms). And if the user keep on zooming in the delay time, there will be no outgoing request at the server.

My OL version is 4.0.1

I didn't find any solution yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is such a delay already, and it is determined by the browser's `requestAnimationFrame` handling. So it's a delay of about 16ms. Also note that zooming will not result in a new request as long as the view is still animating or the user is interacting (e.g. with the mouse wheel).